# Scraper not extracting url link:

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Hi I am trying to scrape the Amazon url address on this site linked under "View item on Amazon".

My code is below, I get zero response. Appreciate any assistance. Thanks

```
import requests
url = "https://app.jumpsend.com/deals/230513"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

tags = soup.find_all('a')

for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href'))
```

Comment: Print `data` and you will see.

Answer (score 2):

The Amazon link ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MH9DK5B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MH9DK5B)) isn't in the html page source. You need to use Selenium in order to read-in the html of all the elements that are set by Java script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://app.jumpsend.com/deals/230513"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'deal-modal-link'})['href']
```

The above code prints out the Amazon link:

```
'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MH9DK5B'
```